# Which ARM architectures have Out-Of-Order-Execution?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture

Which ARM architectures have Out-Of-Order-Execution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not a matter of architecture but of implementation.

In ARM terminology, the *architecture* is the description of the accepted opcodes and behavior. For instance, the ARMv4T architecture mandates support for the old ARM opcodes, and the Thumb opcodes. Any implementation of a given architecture is free to support the architecture in any way that it sees fit. This may or may not include out-of-order execution. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture), the Cortex-A9 uses out-of-order execution, whereas the Cortex-A8 does not; however, both implement the same ARM architecture (ARMv7-A).

Comment: How deep is the out-of-order queue? This document says "partially out of order": https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a9

Answer (score 2):

ARM has also said the Cortex-A15 implementation uses out-of-order execution.